# probability of choosing the i-th red ball from a basket containing $m$ and $n$ indexed red and black balls respectively

Tags: probability

A basket contains $m$ and $n$ red and black balls resp. indexed $\{R_1,...,R_m,B_1,...,B_n\}$

We perform the action of withdrawing $k$ balls from the basket, putting each ball aside (without putting it back).

Does it matter that the black balls are indexed or not?

The probability of the $i-th$ ball being chosen is $\frac{{n+m-1\choose k}}{n+m\choose k-1}$ if the black balls are indistinguishable, because there are ${n+m-1\choose k-1}$ possibilities of success (picking the $R_i$ ball and $k-1$ other balls) and ${n+m\choose k}$ total possibilities. But what if the black balls are indexed from $1$ to $n$? Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the $i$-th red ball is one of the chosen balls is $\frac{k}{m+n}$.

This because $k$ of the $m+n$ balls are selected.

Btw, this is true for every  fixed ball.

No matter whether the black balls are numbered or not.

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: Yeah thanks, does that probability also correspond to the event where the black balls are indexed?

Comment: Yes. It does not matter whether the black balls wear a label or not.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit why that's true? Because that was really my question

Comment: It is just plain thinking. If there are $m+n$ balls and one of them is fixed. Then the probability that this fixed ball will belong to a selection of $k$ balls will be $\frac{k}{m+n}$. It is like buying a lot in a lottery with $m+n$ lots and $k$ prices. The probability that you win is price is $\frac{k}{m+n}$, right? Labeling of the objects (lots, balls) plays not really a part in this.

Comment: You could also say:there are $\binom{m+n-1}{k-1}$ selections that include the fixed ball on a total of $\binom{m+n}{k}$ selections. That gives probability $\binom{n+m-1}{k-1}/\binom{n+m}{k}=\frac{k}{n+m}$.

Answer (score 0):

The counting you've already done is the counting you get when the black balls are indexed but we don't care about the sequence in which the $k$ balls were drawn.
For example, with $m = n = 5,$ $k = 4,$ and $i = 1,$ one of the $\binom{n+m-1}{k-1}$ subsets of balls including $R_i$ is $\{R_1, R_3, B_2, B_3\}.$

If you truly consider the black balls indistinguishable, but the red balls are indexed, and you only want to count distinguishable configurations, then the total number of configurations and the number that contain $R_i$ both will be smaller than you computed. 
For example,
$\{R_1, R_3, B_1, B_2\},$ $\{R_1, R_3, B_1, B_5\},$ and
$\{R_1, R_3, B_3, B_5\}$
count as three separate outcomes if we index the black balls,
but if we don't distinguish the black balls these are all part of the single outcome
$\{R_1, R_3, 2\times B\}.$

The configurations with indistinguishable black balls also won't have uniform probability except under a very contrived mechanism for choosing the balls, so it would be difficult to justify a probability based on the ratio of those two numbers.